# Add TextField in a listView with the feature to update the model on exit using wicket 1.4

Tags: scala, wicket, wicket-1.4

I'm trying to add TextField in a listView  that can update a model on exit or after update the text on it.

I have received a [wonderful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16147101/220175) solution for this listed bellow but it seems works 
in wicket 6.7.0, I guess?

```
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.attributes.{ThrottlingSettings, AjaxRequestAttributes}


 val detail = new TextField("detail", new PropertyModel[Meeting](meeting, "description"))
      detail.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior(("keyup")) {
        protected def onUpdate(target: AjaxRequestTarget) {
          meeting.salvarMeetingInfo(meeting)
        }

        protected override def updateAjaxAttributes(attributes: AjaxRequestAttributes) {
          attributes.setThrottlingSettings(new ThrottlingSettings("thr", Duration.milliseconds(800.0)))
          super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes)
        }
})
item.add(detail)

//Error messages
      scala: object attributes is not a member of package org.apache.wicket.ajax
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.attributes.{ThrottlingSettings, AjaxRequestAttributes}

                              ^

scala: not found: type AjaxRequestAttributes
        protected override def updateAjaxAttributes(attributes: AjaxRequestAttributes) {
                                                            ^
```

But I need to use wicket 1.4, so there is an similar implementation or solution of the code above for wicket 1.4?

Thanks for someone that could help me.

Comment: Yes, I've used the latest version(6.7) in that code, if it was useful accept the answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `updateAjaxAttributes` method in 1.4 call method `setThrottleDelay` on the behaviour instead. [See](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxEventBehavior.html#setThrottleDelay%28org.apache.wicket.util.time.Duration%29) docs for the details.